# Can we add `-fcall-used-REG` for specific functions on gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

Can we tell to gcc that specific functions don't need to store/restore some callee save registers by a function attribute?
We can tell it by `-fcall-used-REGS` for a file, but all of functions in the file are affected.

I made an assembler code which store some callee save registers (r12 on x86_64, for example) and want to call some C functions from asm code. Called functions don't need to store/restore callee save registers because asm code store/restore them, so saving callee save registers are simply overhead (called functions are enough small, so the overhead of pro/epilogue code is huge).

Answer (score -1):

It might be possible with pragma/attribute optimize, but really you should just put the functions in their own files. These functions have to be entirely self-contained since they're using non-default ABI. Putting functions in their own files is a good habit to get in anyway.

Comment: Just to add some links, [pragma optimize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) and the [optimize attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-optimize-function-attribute).  But I agree, with R these are bad ideas.  Indeed, I'd be looking to see if I could either write the asm in C (my first choice), or write the callbacks in asm.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't add this option with attribute:
https://gist.github.com/ko1/d8b35bf015217a39d6b49a5f3918ba8a
> `__attribute__((optimize("-fcall-used-r12"))) void func_w_opt(void)`

Comment: A few points: 1) You're using the attribute incorrectly.  It goes after the return type, not before.  2) Using it correctly won't help.  Apparently gcc doesn't permit this option on functions, giving `bad option`. 3) Using `#pragma optimize` doesn't give an error, but I'm not convinced it's working as intended either. 4) Using `-fcall-used-r12` from the command line is giving the results I expect.  That said, I still think this whole idea is risky.  It seems like there are other approaches to give optimized results.  But I can't recommend one without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Ok, conclusion, it seems the answer for the original question is "impossible".